# Large data storage in ROS community

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have test data (.bag files) each of which is several MB large and don't fit to development repository. [Someone suggests me](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/issues/38) to put those files on http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/ but I don't seem to find how and where I can. If I'm allowed to do so then how?

[DevelopersGuide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/DevelopersGuide#Large_data_files.2C_Large_test_files) says https://code.ros.org/gf/project/data is the right place that sounds outdated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73516/large-data-storage-in-ros-community/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are working to setup downloads.ros.org as a replacement for pr.willowgarage.com.  We will create a way to submit data to be hosted there.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you would have to get someone at Willow to upload it for you. Personally, I would create a second repository on github (perhaps _test_data) and put the larger files in there. Then with github, you can use *raw* urls to access the large bagfiles. It's not ideal if you are changing the large bagfiles often, but it does have the added advantage that your test data is at least in the same github organization as your code, and therefore maybe easier to find than on pr.willowgarage.com

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-18**:
Thx. I might do as you suggest, which I don't see any problem. For the moment I just feel like hearing other opinions too, especially if storing on ROS-aggregated site has any advantage / if there's a reason for ROS test data to be gathered at one place.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-08-18**:
Ah, I see there is actually some movement on this ticket: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/1614

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-08-18**:
Also, github has added file size limits :( : https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota